# Xcode 6.1.1 linker error with AlamoFire

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

All,

I'm running into a weird issue, and I can't find anything about this...

I'm adding `AlamoFire` via `CocoaPods`, and as a result I'm getting this error:

```
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: unknown option character `X' in: -Xlinker
```

this specificially seems to be the part that I don't know how to handle:
**unknown option character `X' in: -Xlinker**

My project is in Objective C, and I don't know if the issue is that AlamoFire is in Swift?

Comment: @zellb that was the issue...want to put your comment in an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Posted it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you use CocoaPods 0.36 beta ? What really did the trick for me in this case was completely uninstalling cocoa pods, reinstalling it using

```
gem install cocoapods --pre
```

and then installing Alamofire as described in their github page